# Center Excel Window in Center of Screen

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing an app in Excel, however it only takes up a small amount of "real estate" on the worksheet. I've got the code below to resize the window appropriately on open, however it does not open in the center of the screen. How can I do this? Thanks!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Toggle False 'toggle off excel ribbon, headings, scroll bars, formula & status bars
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Width = 358
    Application.Height = 324
    'irrelevant code
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to change `Application.Top` and `Application.Left` property.

Comment: Interesting solution without API [Set Excel window position to center](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/96891-set-excel-window-position-to-center/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" _
(ByVal Index As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Index As Long) As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ScreensWidth As Single
    Dim ScreensHeight As Single

    ScreensWidth = GetSystemMetrics(78)
    ScreensHeight = GetSystemMetrics(79)
   
    ScreensWidth = ConvertPixelsToPoints(ScreensWidth, "X")
    ScreensHeight = ConvertPixelsToPoints(ScreensHeight, "Y")
    
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Width = 358
        .Height = 324
    
        .Left = (ScreensWidth - .Width) / 2
        .Top = (ScreensHeight - .Height) / 2
    End With
End Sub

Private Function ConvertPixelsToPoints(ByVal pxls As Single, _
                                       ByVal XorY As String) As Single
    Dim hDC As Long

    hDC = GetDC(0)
    If XorY = "X" Then ConvertPixelsToPoints = pxls * (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, 88))
    If XorY = "Y" Then ConvertPixelsToPoints = pxls * (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, 90))
    Call ReleaseDC(0, hDC)
End Function
```

To understand what each API does, I would point you to my favorite site for [API List](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php)

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: @SiddharthRout Imo incomplete VBA7 syntax, afaik needing **`LongPtr` type** 
(2) GetDC: both the `hWnd` argument as well as the function result itself,
(3) ReleaseDC: both arguments, i.e. `hWnd` and `hDC`,
(4) GetDeviceCaps: only the `hDC` arg; whereas function (1) `GetSystemMetrics` rests unchanged :-)